# Is there anyway to convert some cards to a checklist in Trello?

Tags: trello

I see you can convert checklist items to a card. Can you convert the other way (take a list of cards and convert to checklist)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no feature to do this in Trello. However, since you can create multiple checklist items in one go by pasting multiple lines into the add checklist item field, all you really need is a list of card names to copy from.

If you don't mind fiddling a bit, you can export your whole board to a JSON file and then print a list of all card names fairly easily like this:

```
perl -MJSON -l -0 -e 'print $_->{name} for (@{decode_json(<STDIN>)->{cards}})' < board.json
```

This assumes that the cards you want to convert are basically one-liners as it ignores any description, checklists, etc. in them

Another option would be to export the cards to a CSV file but that requires the paid "Business Class" license.

Comment: If you're comfortable with giving 3rd party apps access to Trello, there is also a Chrome app that exports to an Excel file, and a web app that lists all your card titles in a plain text list for easy copypasta.  


- [Export for Trello - Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-for-trello/nhdelomnagopgaealggpgojkhcafhnin?hl=en-US)  


- [Contractor](http://contractor.launchpadlab.com/)  


EDIT: Links are good. I forget that pressing "Enter" in comments saves the edits. // EDIT 2: Markdown doesn't allow newlines on comments?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the board to markdown using [trello-board-to-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trello-board-to-markdown)
2. Create a trello checklist
3. Paste the required text into it. Trello will separate lines into different todos.

Alt: If you can't do the above, or don't want to share Trello keys, then print to pdf and manually copy and paste it, which will include checklists (badly formatted).